# Oracle WITH clause and grouping by results

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two tables: a product table and a territory table. The product tables holds IDs of products and the territory code denoting which countries they can be sold in:

```
PRODUCT:

PRODUCT_ID  | TERRITORY_CODE
----------------------------
   PROD1    |       2
   PROD2    |       0
   PROD3    |       1
   PROD4    |       0
   PROD5    |       2
   PROD6    |       0
   PROD7    |       2
```

The second table table holds a territory code and the corresponding ISO code of countries it's allowed to be sold in. For example:

```
TERRITORY:

TERRITORY_CODE | COUNTRY_CODE
---------------------------
      0        |     US
      1        |     CA
      2        |     US
      2        |     CA
```

I would like to write a query that counts the number of `PRODUCT_IDs` using `COUNTRY_CODE` as a key.

For example, I want to know how many distinct products there are for sale in the US. I don't want to have to know that `0` and `2` are territory codes that contain the US, I just want to look up by `COUNTRY_CODE`. How can I do this?

In some preliminary research, I've found that a `WITH` clause may be useful, and came up with the following query:

```
WITH country AS (
  SELECT (DISTINCT COUNTRY_CODE)
  FROM TERRITORY
) 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) 
FROM country c,
PRODUCT p
WHERE p.TERRITORY_CODE=c.TERRITORY_ID;
```

However, this doesn't produce the expected result. I also can't get it to group by `COUNTRY_CODE`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the SQL in your example might be incomplete.  `TERRITORY_ID` does not seem to be in `country`.

Comment: Do you only have unique instances of `product_id`, or is it only unique per-`territory_code`?  Answers will be different.

Comment: Product IDs are unique. A `territory_code` can be the same for many product IDs. On the territory side, a territory_code has many country_codes, and a country_code may belong to many territory_codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `GROUP BY`.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT T.Country_Code, COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) 
FROM Product P
JOIN Territory T ON P.Territory_Code = T.Territory_Code
GROUP BY T.Country_Code
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79f17/3).

Good luck.